# Visual Studio Code Python terminal doesn't like input()

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, terminal

I recently started learning python after learning web development. I wanted to try out my first program in my VSCode terminal, but it doesn't work. My program does work though in my Mac terminal. I have the latest VSCode version and MacOS Mojave. I use Python 3.8. I run the code with the "Code Runner" plug-in.

This is my program:

```
import random
import sys
print('ROCK, PAPER, SCRISSORS')
wins = 0
losses = 0
ties = 0
while True:
    print('--- %s Wins, %s Losses, %s ties ---' % (wins, losses, ties))
    while True: #This While loop activates if a user doesn't type 'r', 'p', 's', or 'q'.
        print(
            "Enter a move: -|- rocks = r, paper = p, scissors = s -|- You can quit by typing 'q'")
        userMove = input()
        if userMove == 'q':
            sys.exit()
        elif userMove == 'r' or userMove == 's' or userMove == 'p':
            break
    randomNumber = random.randint(1, 3)
    myMove = ''
    losing = 'You lost'
    winning = 'You won!!!'
    tie = 'It s a tie. I will beat you later!'
    if randomNumber == 1:
        myMove = 'rock'
    elif randomNumber == 2:
        myMove = 'paper'
    else:
        myMove = 'scissors'
    if (userMove == 'r' and myMove == 'paper' or userMove == 'p' and myMove == 'rock' or userMove == 's' and myMove == 'paper'):
        print(winning)
        wins = wins + 1
    elif (userMove == 'r' and myMove == 'rock' or userMove == 'p' and myMove == 'paper' or userMove == 's' and myMove == 'scissors'):
        print(tie)
        ties = ties + 1
    elif (userMove == 'r' and myMove == 'scissors' or userMove == 'p' and myMove == 'scissors' or userMove == 's' and myMove == 'rock'):
        print(losing)
        losses = losses + 1
```

It's basically a simple rock-paper-scissors game. When I type in 'r', 'p' or 's', it says this:

'NameError: name 'r' is not defined'

I also tried running the mac terminal in vscode, but that didn't work for some reason.

Is this a bug, or is this my fault? Any answers would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

It's an error in my "Code Runner" plug-in. If you have experienced the same issue, go to your Code Runner JSON settings, and change "Python -u" to "python3".

Comment: There is no problem with the code it is working well in jupyter notebook

Comment: you are using python 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried running your program inside [eric6 IDE](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/index.html) and inside Python IDLE and it worked without any problems/issues.

If you have multiple Python versions (specifically Python 2.x), in the lower left corner check if the Python version you are using isn't actually 2.x since in Python 2 you use **raw_input** instead of **input** and could explain the behavior you are getting.

If that doesn't work, this will probably be an issue from VS Code's side.

Comment: Thanks! I used Python 3.8, and it now works if i click: "Run python file in terminal". It seems my "Code runner" plug-in doesn't work then. I will now edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using python 2? (you can tell by running `python -V`)

You really should switch to python3 if possible, but if not, you should use the 'raw_input' function rather than the 'input' function

in python2, the input() function evaluates the user's input as a python expression. This means if I input `2+2`, you won't get a string containing "2+2" but `4`

And if you input a letter (`p` in your example), it will try to find a variable named like that. Since you don't have a `p` variable in your code, it throws an error.

Comment: Thanks! I am using Python 3.8, but still thanks for your help.